# need to get back up to speed with .net/c# since 2018

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I started using .Net when it first came out 15 years ago (v1.0).   My last experience was writing an enterprise-wide API in 2018 using Web API.

I've been focusing in React and Azure since then.  What is the latest and greatest way to write web services in .Net now?  Is it still "Web API"?  Or is there a new preferred way to write web services on .Net Core 3.0 that I should learn?

I see a lot more job postings for .Net Core now.  It seems like a lot more companies have bought into .Net core at this point.  Has Microsoft announced an end of support date for .Net standard?

Are there any new framework features or language syntax that I should be familiar with?

Comment: `Has Microsoft announced an end of support date for .Net standard?` https://www.google.com/search?q=Has+Microsoft+announced+an+end+of+support+date+for+.Net+standard https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Answer (score 2):

There's just ASP.NET Core now. You can create API-style controllers or MVC-style controllers/views (or Razor Pages, Blazor, etc.) all in the same project. There's templates for things like an API, but this just gives you a starter; it doesn't confine you to one approach or another.

In general ASP.NET Web Api was just about REST-style applications; ASP.NET Core has the same thing. However, it also supports gRPC and OData, and can be made to work with GraphQL. Any of these can be used to create "web services".

.NET Standard is an abstraction, not a framework. Each successive version of the .NET Standard gains a wider API footprint, encompassing more of the .NET frameworks (.NET Framework proper, but also Unity, Xamarin, Mono, and .NET Core) under its umbrella. .NET Standard isn't going anywhere, per se. However, .NET Core is gaining more an more features from .NET Framework, and has basically already surpassed it. The next major version of .NET Core will actually be ".NET 5". .NET Framework will go away (though still be supported by Microsoft for legacy apps), and Unity, Xamarin, and Mono APIs will be rolled in, to create one .NET to rule them all. Long and short, yes, .NET Core should be your focus.